# How to make eclipse recognize the correct file extension/open the correct editor for files opened outside of the scope of a project?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, content-assist

I have a simple file `index.jsp` outside of a project in a location such as `/home/user/other/` and I open it in eclipse with `File - Open file`. The file opens but things such as content assist are not working.

I tried creating a file inside an eclipse project (with `File - new - jsp file`) and everything works (including content assist).

Is there a way to force eclipse to open the proper editor for files opened outside the scope of a project?

Edit: I'm running eclipse indigo for java ee.

There seems to be a problem with the file not being in a project. I tried moving the file inside a project and now it works. I still want to know how to make this work outside a project though.

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you running? I don't have this problem. My first assumption is that there's something wrong with the file. Have you tried a different one?

Comment: Edited. @Jeremy Eclipse indigo for java ee.

Answer (score 3):

Are the file associations set correctly in your eclipse version?

This can be done under Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations

You can set the desired editors for each file extension there. You can also set multiple editors for file associations. In that case you should set the default associated editor to the desired one.

When the default editor is set to your desired one, it should open files from outside of your project with this one.

Comment: I've checked the file associations before asking the question and they look OK. JSP files are set to open with the JSP Editor.

Comment: For JSP, my associations are JSP Editor, Weg Page Editor, Text Editor and CSS JSP Editor. Also, there seems to be information in the Preferences -> General -> Content Type panel, too.

Comment: Is there also a default editor set? I have set the default for jsp files to JSP Editor (default is shown in brackets) and for me it works also when the files are not part of any project.

Comment: @david.dionis Yes, the default editor is JSP Editor. What eclipse version are you using BTW?

Comment: @Guest I use eclipse indigo and installed all plugins i need manually. Could you try to remove all other editors from the jsp association?

Answer (score 0):

For JSP files specifically, Java content assist will not work outside the workspace since it relies on a project's Java Build Path (you'll find the same limitations opening .java files).  This is normal.